# How to get Lazy image like Jet.com

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, products, product-images

How can I set my logo like jet.com before loading images
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the **Product** **Placeholder** **Image** in the backend or admin panel of your Magento installation. If you are facing any problem please let me know.

[Please check this link for you reference.](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-change-default-placeholder-image.html#gref)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the question was referring to, based on those screenshots it seems that the images are loaded via AJAX and the placeholder only displays before those images have loaded. Won't this admin change only affect products that don't have any images set?

Comment: HI, Ben Crook,  I need same as like Jet.com How can I get same as like that? Is there any extension for this?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement here is free extension is available, you can use this ready solution.

https://github.com/mgtcommerce/Mgt_LazyImageLoader

after installing this extension , include this extension in your page by modifying its

`mgt_lazy_image_loader.xml`

IN your case you need to modify as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/lazy-image-loader.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/common.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/lazy-image-loader.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/common.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
    <catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/lazy-image-loader.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/common.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
    <!--for home page-->
    <cms_index_index translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/jquery-1.7.2.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/lazy-image-loader.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/common.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
    <!--end for home page-->
</layout>
```

after that

for those image you want to lazy load modify `img` tag as below

```
<img class="lazy" src="getSkinUrl('images/mgt_lazy_image_loader/loader.gif'); ?>" data-src="helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

add class `lazy` and put lazy image placeholder in `src` and put your orignal image in `data-src` attribute

Comment: HI Thanks for your answer. I'll try and update with you

Comment: I tried on my dev [site](http://rajivpastula.com/magento/) but it is not showing. I am using custom design so I need to change any path? Please check my site and suggest me.

Comment: @Murtuza : after install, my product listing page image is empty, what i need to do?

Comment: @Rathinam remove jquery from layout `js/mgt_lazy_image_loader/jquery-1.7.2.min.js` becuase your theme might already include it

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala I am removed the file -> skin\frontend\default\default\js\mgt_lazy_image_loader\jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala I am removed the file -> skin\frontend\default\default\js\mgt_lazy_image_loader\jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala and add -> https://justpaste.it/74c6o into app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml, cleared cache, still category product listing shows without images screenshot : https://snag.gy/dS9GTf.jpg how can i solve this error?